# Kentico Facebook logon web part not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am using the Kentico Facebook Logon web part on my page. I have set the "**App ID**" and "**App secret**" in the setting for the Facebook authentication.

**Problem**: I am not able to see the web part contents like username, password

I have attached a screenshot below.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see in this browser because you are logged in already.

Try open a different browser that you are not logged in or InPrivate View, then you would see a Facebook button, once clicked, it will pop up the username/password panel.

[image]

Comment: Can I know if i can include the step for email verification after the user clicks on the "Log In" button shown in the above pop up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try to attach a custom method to the authentication event and trigger the email. But the user would be enabled already so the verification is point less, unless you change that functionality as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but thanks for confirming. Now I have to change the whole process/ workflow though to include the email verification step. Really Thanks for your time and great explanation.